# How does Page_Unload work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, page-lifecycle

I noticed the Unload being called after Load. I thought Unload was suppose to be called before a page is destroyed. For example, if I redirect from A to B. Before redirecting from A, isn't suppose to Unload event fire there? My logic come from mobile apps life cycle.

I need to remove some session variables when the page is changed and I thought that was the right place. Is there somewhere else I should do this?

The way I'm solving it is removing sessions when the page that's using them is called. On the Onload event when it's not postback, to be more precise. I'd prefer to call it before destruction, just to be sure that's being removed when that same page is call from somewhere else.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use `ViewState` which would be specific to the individual page that you're on..? this would be the better option in my opinion

Comment: It's a good option, but right now I'm at a stage where I can't do too many drastic changes to the page cause we hit production in a few days. But I'll consider for a future update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx), it gives you a description of order of events for an ASP.Net page.

For your case, note that Unload is raised every time a request for a Page is processed on the server, doesn't matter if it's a postback or not.

On the server, the page exists only during its processing time, after then the response is sent to client and the page doesn't exists any more. If you see things from this point of view, the "unload" event become meaningful for every processed page

Comment: I've read that page before asking. According to what I understood from that, Unload should get called at the end, but I thought the end was when a page is about to destroy.

Comment: @chelo666 You are missing the correct meaning of "page is about to destroy": in a web application, a page is "destroyed" (on the server) every time is processed. It doesn't matter that you keep seeing it in your browser: the browser is just showing the response received, and will call the server again later when, e.g. , user click a button and generate a new postback request. For this further request, a new "Page" will be created and processed (and Unload will be called at some point near the end of processing)

Comment: So on a browser, even though you can see a specific page, it's still running? That's kind of confusing, but it does answer many previous questions I had asked myself.

Comment: That's how the web works! browser sends a request, the server process the request and return a response, browser parse the response and show you some fancy screen understanding how html tags should be displayed to the user. What you are doing in your server side code is creating a suitable HMTL for the page requested and filling the response. After that, that "page" does not exists any more on server.

Comment: Thanks that sounds quite interesting. The same reason I love telecommunications so abstract, but existent. I know what a request and response is, but how it works is a whole different story and right now I don't have time to learn it. But I will in a near future! I guess I got my answer in a way lol